# EditText expands too slow inside AlertDialog on android

Tags: android, dialog, android-animation, android-alertdialog

Simplifying a more complex problem.

I have an AlertDialog with this view dialog.xml (I might be wrong and this problem has nothing to do with AlertDialog, but Views in general):

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  // <ImageView 48dp x 48dp/> ImageView for profile photo

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>

  // <ImageView 48dp x 48dp> ImageView for a send button.

</LinearLayout>
```

I need this whole dialog to be on the bottom, right above the keyboard, so that it's similar to how the chat programs have it. I need it as floating dialog, because it's not tied to any one place in the parent view.

I do this (in client code) to achieve that:

```
dialog.show();  // above dialog
Window window dialog.getWindow();
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Now when I type, the edit field correctly expands up to 5 lines (from bottom up). But if I type too fast (press enter to create new lines fast), the dialog expand animation (the height increases downward) is slower than the dialog shifts up animation. This causes for a 1-2 seconds when the dialog appears to be floating in the air, with a little gap between its lower border and the keyboard.

How can I prevent that (eliminate this space in between)? Or make the animation take 0 sec?

**To clarify: I do not need to disable animation for dialog popup/dismiss. When the window expands too fast (for example by creating new lines), the window gets shifted up, while the height does not compensate for the shift fast enough leaving a small temporary (1-2sec) gap in between the dialog and keyboard. This might be fundamental problem for floating Views in general (I tried using PopupWindow with the same effect).**

Dialog with the gap:
[image: Dialog with the gap]

Becomes this after 1-2 sec (when the expand animation finally catches up):
[image: Dialog with no gap]

Comment: To clarify: I do not need to disable animation for dialog popup/dismiss. I need to disable animation for dialog shift down and height expand. This might be fundamental problem for floating Views in general (I tried using PopupWindow with the same effect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution on my own after a lot of digging through stack overflow answers with no results.

The idea is to expand the entire dialog first to full screen, but have a transparent overlay view covering empty parts.

The dialog.xml now looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <!-- Transparent view that extends over entire screen and push comment view to the bottom -->
  <View
      android:id="@+id/overlay"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@color/transparent"/>

  <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

    // <ImageView 48dp x 48dp/> ImageView for profile photo

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"/>

    // <ImageView 48dp x 48dp> ImageView for a send button.

  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And for Java code:

```
public void showDialog() {
  View content = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false);

  // This makes top LinearLayout background transparent, without this, 
  // it will be all white covering fullscreen.
  content.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));        

  Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setView(content).create();
  dialog.show(); // needs to be done before window changes
  Window window dialog.getWindow();
  window.setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
  window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);

  View overlay = content.findViewById(R.id.overlay);
  overlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.cancel();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove animation, follow the following steps:

1. Adds a no_anim.xml to */res/anim*, the key is to set duration to 0

   > ```
   > <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   >     android:fromDegrees="0"
   >     android:toDegrees="360"
   >     android:pivotX="50%"
   >     android:pivotY="50%"
   >     android:duration="0" />
   > ```
2. Define a custom style using the 0-duration animation:

> ```
> <style name="NoAnimation">
>     <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/no_anim</item>
>     <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/no_anim</item>
> </style>
> ```

3. Apply the style to your AlertDialog:

> ```
> dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.NoAnimation;
> ```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not help with dialog expanding animation duration.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps? I've tested it and the dialog shows up instantly with no animation.

Comment: My problem is not with dialog showing up without animation. My problem is that the dialog does not expand (when new line is created in EditText) without animation. The animation for expanding is this: move dialog up -> increase the height of the dialog to accommodate increased height of EditText. Because these two do not work in parallel, but sequential, there is a small gap in between the dialog and keyboard for a short amount of time.

Comment: You do realize your title is exceedingly misleading